# How would format this in a single while loop so that it would print as four columns?

Tags: java

I need to make this into four separate columns

```
 public class Lab7aCelsiustoFahrenheit
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
        //variables
       double orig = -40.0;
       double cels = orig;
       double fahr = cels;
       final int MAX_TEMP = -1;      
         //loop that prints asingle column on celsius to F conversions
         while(cels <= MAX_TEMP)
         {
            System.out.println(cels + "C " + "is " + fahr + "F" + "\t");
            cels++;
            fahr = (((9.0 * cels) + 160) / 5);

            }

     }    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that edit. Its my first time and the formatting is slightly confusing

Comment: What do you mean four different columns? What do you need as output exactly?

Comment: Depending on the requirements of your homework assignment, one possibility would be to use two loops. The first would put all the results into an array. The second would cycle only a quarter of the times of the actual array length. Each cycle would get the first value from each of the quartiles of the array and string build them into a column.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a linebreak after 4 entries, in counting how many items u wrote and then start in the next line.

Also to have each "cell" below the other you should use `System.out.printf` for writing the entry to format the `double`-values

If you really want to do this in a single while-loop, a possibilty would be:

```
int column = 1;

while(cels <= MAX_TEMP) {
    fahr = (((9.0 * cels) + 160) / 5);

    System.out.printf("%8.2fC is %8.2fF" + "\t", cels, fahr);
    cels++;
    column++;

    if(column > 4) {
        column = 1;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I think you should also do the calculation before System.out.printf(...)